# Installing visual studio on Xbox one/Scorpio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, xbox-one

I am wondering if I can install visual studio on Xbox one and later on Scorpio?
As you know they are running windows 10 and have a very powerful CPU/RAM and GPU. But in the [Microsoft dev center page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/development-environment-setup) they've said that

> "The Universal Windows Platform (UWP) on Xbox development environment
>   consists of a development PC connected to an Xbox One console through
>   a local network."

Isn't there a way to work with an XBox as an stand alone development environment?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but my assumption is that the dev tools typically require the desktop shell which the XBOX doesn't have even if some other parts of the OS are shared.

Comment: Although I could imagine VS Code might work.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, thanks a lot . for the response. So I need a good PC beside my xbox to write games. Right? what about Scorpio? Do you expect to see any difference?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

Whole XBox is rebooted in development mode which is one more level of isolation.

In this mode Visual Studio Pro may be used to build and deploy UWP apps.

Visual Studio Code sources are available on GitHub. Feel free to try to build and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is simply **no, it's not possible to install Visual Studio on Xbox One**.

The Xbox One developer mode is isolated, and it can't install Win32 applications like Visual Studio (Though, it's probably possible to install console applications or just simple apps that runs on background, since the Xbox One OS is based on Windows).

### The solution

If you have a computer that have Windows or macOS (Maybe Linux with Wine), you can install Visual Studio 2019 for free and install these components :

- The UWP Devkit
- The C++ or C# module (Or both if you combine different languages)
  And that's it. Your app will be compatible with Xbox One and Windows because it's universal.

But, don't forget to read that to make sure your application will work as expected on Xbox One: [UWP features not supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox)

If you need more details, you can see the [Getting started with UWP app development on Xbox One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/getting-started)

Comment: I didn't see that the post was pretty old, but maybe it will help future people :)